# Highcharts not rendering properly on legend clicks

Tags: javascript, jquery, charts, highcharts

**Problem:**
When series of the charts are set hidden and visible by clicking the legends the YAxis on right side do not render properly:

```
enter code here
```

http://jsfiddle.net/yzqdekhr/5/

**Steps To Reproduce**:

1) Click Diversion % Monthly Legend and Hide right side y axis
2) Click on both Diverted Tons and Trash Tons Legend (Complete chart will be blank)
3) Click Diversion % Monthly Legend to show it again
4) Click both Diverted Tons and Trash Tons Legend to show chart data

See now both axis have their own plotlines which should not be, see below image

[image]

**Expected Result** 
Plot lines must be common as in the first load

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/yzqdekhr/5/

Comment: not able to understand the issue, everything looks fines, I tried to reproduce using your steps

Comment: did you tried the steps above, at first there were only 4 gridlines / plot lines but after performing steps above the lines turned to be 9,

Comment: yes tried your steps

Comment: at first there were only 4 gridlines / plot lines but after performing steps above the lines turned to be 9,

Comment: Similar problem addressed very well here http://jsfiddle.net/7NEhU/

Answer (score 1):

This is a known issue reported as a bug here - https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/issues/4374

Suggested workaround is to add a wrapper that will realign ticks.

```
H.wrap(H.Axis.prototype, 'setScale', function(p) {
        if(this.options.alignTicks !== false || this.chart.options.alignTicks !== false) {
             this.forceRedraw = true;   
        }
        p.call(this);
    });
})(Highcharts)
```

JSFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/q6sr1c0f/

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with how the secondary axis acts - when removing all and drawing the `Diversion %` there is no data or primary axis to be dynamically linked to.

The only way I can think of doing what you want without getting the double axis line is to set the second Yaxis `linkedTo` option to the first one.

This will make sure that if there is no first Yaxis the plot will not render new lines. This present another problem because now the `Diversion %` line is not painted at all (if the others are not visible) so you will have to set a `min` and `max` value for the first Yaxis.

[JSnippet Demo](https://www.jsnippet.net/snippet/411/highcharts-usage-example-with-exporting-extension)

```
//Added to the second Yaxis:
linkedTo: 0;

//Added to the first Yaxis:
min: 0;
max: 100;
```

Comment: I can't do that as 1st Y axis may have values in thousands,millions and all but 2nd axis may have values only from 0 to 100

Comment: see this http://forum.highcharts.com/viewtopic.php?f=9&t=17114 and the fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/7NEhU/